# ScanGear only working for some users

Tags: scanner, canon

The scanner software ScanGear is failing for one user but working for me. Running `scangearmp` for either of us finds the scanner:

[image: Screenshot of selecting a scanner]

Then on pressing ‘OK’, I get to scan documents but my child gets an error message: “ScanGear: Internal Error occurred. Scanner driver will be closed.”:

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

This is on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa), both users on the same laptop, just with separate user accounts. I have added my child's user to the `scanner` group.

What can I try to make scanning work for all users? Thanks.

Comment: Don't have experience with 2-users-on-one-pc issue but have had similiar problem with 2-users-on-one-lan. Only one user can connect to the scanner at a time. If you restart the laptop, let the child sign on (and not you) does it work? If no, different problem.

Comment: Good idea, @OrganicMarble. Unfortunately it didn't work. I rebooted the laptop (and the scanner), logged in as my child before me, and tried running `scangearmp` first as the child. Same error message as above. Switching to my user, `scapgearmp` still worked fine.

Comment: I found a real multiuser machine with scangear on it and it worked for both users. A couple of questions: how is the printer connected - usb, lan, samba? How are you starting scangear - command line, desktop shortcut?

Comment: Thanks. Lan, with both laptop and printer on the same wi-fi network. Initially I was starting ScanGear from inside The Gimp, from the Create menu. For debugging I've been typing the scangearmp command at a MATE Terminal.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much the same as our setup. Let me see if I can get it to fail.

Comment: It would be interesting to find what actually fails - so you think you could get a `strace` and find what's failing?

Comment: Thanks so much, @jpalecek — that's fixed it. I've never used `strace` before, so wouldn't've thought of that. Tracing both the working and non-working invocations, the difference was on `chmod("/var/tmp/canon_sgmp_setting_common.ini", 0666) = 0`. That file was owned by my user, with full `rw-rw-rw-` privs for all — presumably set by this line when I fist ran it, trying to ensure all users can write to it. Which they can, but not `chmod` it.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. However, this is an example of very sloppy programming, if not a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to remove `/var/tmp/canon_sgmp_setting_common.ini`, by the user who can use the scanner (or `root`).

`scangearmp` creates that file if it doesn't already exist and tries to make it writeable by all, even if it already is. But it only has permission to do so if it owns the file, meaning that in practice once `scangearmp` has run, it can only be run again by the same user until that file is deleted.

Thank you, @jpalecek, for pointing me in the right direction.